# Regarding good practices with scheduling in Java

Tags: java, scheduling

I'm building a game from the ground up in Java, using only standard libraries. So far I've got a game that prints ASCII characters in a swing window to represent 3d objects. It's pretty cool. Anyway, since I don't know about threading or scheduling, I'm wondering if I'm using some bad practices that could cause issues later on. I have one repeating task running to update the level every tenth of a second, but whenever I want to delay something, I use

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule... etc etc.
```

Is it good to make a "new scheduled thread pool" every time I want a new delayed task to run once, or should I try to keep one instance going? If it's good to reuse instances, when is it appropriate to make a new one?

Comment: In Swing, it might be better to use a Swing `Timer`.  Another solution might be to use a custom `Thread`.  In either case, you'd have these executing at a "regular" interval (using `sleep` in the thread to reduce the overhead).  Any of the three cases, understand, that these mechanisms only guarantee "at least" precision - that is, they will only "delay" for "at least" the specified period, but normally longer. The "answer" is - it depends.  I would think it's unusual to use `Executors` for this purpose and they might not provide you with level of accuracy you really want

Comment: Have you read through some of the tutorials on concurrency in Java? It's changed a lot in recent versions with much simpler solutions for most common use cases.

Comment: I would also think that `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule` is a bad idea, as you should have maintained a reference to the first executor you created and re-use it, otherwise you run the risk of multiple threads executing simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency in Swing applications is tricky: everything that impacts the GUI needs to be executed on a single thread (called the event-dispatch thread). So when you set up a separate thread to perform some long-running background task (e.g. generating a map for an area the player isn't viewing yet) then you need to work carefully to synchronise with anything that might impact the GUI.

In general you have two options for the simpler use cases:

- If it's a short activity that immediately impacts the GUI then use a `Timer` to trigger an event on the event-dispatch thread. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).
- If it's a long activity then use a `SwingWorker`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

There are plenty of other ways to achieve interaction with other threads (e.g. see `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`) but given you have said you are just starting out I would suggest sticking to one of those two for now. They take care of most of the complexity for you and let you focus on your game logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not really sure I'd call this a swing application though. Originally it actually just rendered everything in System.outs. Now it uses a single swing window, with a single text panel, and a single method that updates it. None of my other tasks directly interact with the swing window, it's just game logic stuff. That said, is all this swing stuff still relevant?

Comment: @Freelix2000 yes the Swing stuff is still relevant. Even if you have just a single Swing window it is still a Swing application and that means you need to be careful about the threads that update the GUI. I suggest you start with `Timer` and look at other options if that causes issues.

Comment: Only one thread updates the GUI, and I don't think I'll ever make another. That's why this was more a general scheduling question than a swing question. Still, I'll definitely look into swing timers and maybe make a switch to them in what I've already written. Thanks for the help.